# Nativescript 7 - Image Tag Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Images not Loading)

Tags: angular, nativescript

Images aren't loading.

I'm getting the error:

```
Error in reading bitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/org.nativescript.testdemo/files/app/images/testimage.png (No such file or directory)
```

The folder structure "appears" fine but clearly both iOS and Android are not seeing the images.

so, I added 'images' to the assets folder and also tried adding the following line in webpack.config.js to see if it would use the images folder:

```
{ from: 'images/**', noErrorOnMissing: true, globOptions: { dot: false, ...copyIgnore } },
```

HTML is set like this:

```
<Image src="~/images/testimage.png"></Image>
```

Also tried the variant to no avail (after placing the images folder inside the assets folder):

```
<Image src="~/assets/images/testimage.png"></Image>
```

I also tried configuring webpack.config.js per the Github link below.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2280)

I'm running:
Nativescript 7.0.10
Angular 10.1.0

package.json

```
"@nativescript/android": "7.0.0",
"@nativescript/ios": "7.0.3",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it for me.

Unfortunately, there's no documentation that specifies this change.

I moved the assets, fonts, and my images folder to the `src` directory.

old folder structure:

```
src
- assets
- images
- fonts
```

new folder structure:

```
src
- app
assets
images
fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolve it by moving images from `src/app/images` to `src/assets/images/*`. The path could look like: `~/assets/images/logo.png`